# Does Ubuntu 20.04 still boot if I remove the whole /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft directory?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I deleted the Windows partition on my Dell Notebook and installed there Kubuntu 20.04. The grub boot menu still shows "Windows Boot Manager". I want to remove this line by removing the directory "/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft" and executing update-grub. Are there any keys or certificates for secure boot in this directory? Can I boot ubuntu after I deleted this directory? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your second question is "yes". The first one I'm not too sure about. However, before wiping out parts of the `/EFI` directory, it would be a good idea to make a quick backup using `tar` or `zip`. This way, if something goes sideways, you can restore `/boot` to its previous condition with the help of the Ubuntu installation media.

0. Open Terminal
1. Archive the `/boot/efi` directory:

   ```
   sudo tar -cvf ~/efi.tar /boot/efi
   ```

Once this is done, feel free to remove `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft` and run `update-grub`.

All this aside, if your ultimate goal is simply to remove "Windows Boot Manager" from your list of boot options, you can do that without deleting entire directories.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the Boot Manager:

   ```
   sudo efibootmgr
   ```
2. Find "Windows boot manager" in the list and record (or remember) the number. It will look something like `Boot9999`.
3. Remove Windows from the Boot Manager options:

   ```
   sudo efibootmgr -b 9999 -B
   ```

   **Note:** Be sure to replace `9999` with the number you recorded (or remembered)

That's all there is to it, and your Windows boot manager directory remains intact, though invisible, in the event you need quick access to it in the future.

Comment: You do need to remove UEFI boot entry, but grub will still find Windows boot files in ESP, until you remove that folder. Do not remove /EFI/ubuntu. If you have Windows backup & restore Windows, you can just reinstall/repair Windows boot to restore folders & UEFI entry. You also can turn off grub2's os-prober so it does  not search for other systems if Windows is only other system you have.